# Pattern matching variable ($1) after doing regex giving incorrect value

Tags: regex, perl

I was running a perl script today and was getting a problem. I have identified the underlying problematic code, but not sure what exactly the problem is.

Following is the code which reproduces the problem.

```
use Strict;

my $d1 = "development/source/Utils/THOR.Thunder.Client/Release/THOR.Thunder.pdb";
my $d2 = "development/source/Utils/THOR.Thunder.Client/Release/CF.Thunder.Client.API.Conversion.dll";
my $search = '^development/source/Utils/([^\\\\\/]+)/(install|Release)/';
my $with = '$1/';
print "$d1\n$d2\n$search\n$with\n\n";

if ($d1 =~ m/$search/)
{
print "Yippie 1 $1\n";
}

if ($d2 =~ m/$search/)
{
print "Yippie 2 $1\n";
}


$d1 =~ s/$search/$with/gi;
print("The value of 1 is $1\n"); #Print statement 1
$d2 =~ s/$search/$with/gi;
print("The value of 1 is $1"); #Print statement 2
```

In the above code, both the if conditions are true and $1 is printed as "THOR.Thunder.Client" which is correct. However when it comes to substitution something weird is happening which I can't understand. In print statement 1, $1 is "THOR.Thunder.Client" however in Print statement 2 it is empty. I would expect it to have the same value.

If I however reduce the length of d2 by deleting any 2 characters in "CF.Thunder.Client.API.Conversion.dll", I get the correct result ie $1 in print statement 2 has the value that I want.

Can anybody please explain why this is happening?

Comment: `use Strict`?  Does it even compile?

Comment: @devnull yep it did compile for me. I am using active perl v5.8.8

Comment: could you provide actual and expected output?

Comment: Hmm, I find it weird. I get the results you are looking for by removing the global flag: [codepad demo](http://codepad.org/olLgJaFf) but... [this one](http://codepad.org/W1219g9b)... I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @mpapec - $1 should have the value THOR.Thunder.Client

Comment: @Jerry - Thank you for that. Let me see if I can change it from gi to just to just i.

Comment: 1) `use Strict;` has no effect. You want `use strict;`. 2) Your code gives `THOR.Thunder.Client` for $d2 with 5.10.1 (the older version I have installed) and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain exactly why it is happening, but it seems related to the fact that you are trying to do a global replace even though the search pattern is anchored. It seems this triggers some kind of subtle bug in perl v5.8.8. The same code in perl v5.10.1 works as expected (although the $1 inside $with is not expanded in the replacement in either version).

I would call this a perl bug that seldom appear but you managed to find the exact combination of circumstances to trigger it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @krisku. The $1 I am later expanding in further processing, so not bothered about that at the moment.